# Xamarin for android: unable to play mp3 from external folder

Tags: android, xamarin, audio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am unable to play an mp3 file that I placed in the files folder of my application's external storage.

I requested the permission in OnCreate()

```
    private const int EXTERNAL_READ_WRITE_REQUEST = 1337;

    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[]
        { 
            Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage,
            Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage
        },
        EXTERNAL_READ_WRITE_REQUEST);
    }
```

Then I verified the permission was granted:

```
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        if (requestCode == EXTERNAL_READ_WRITE_REQUEST)
        {
            if (grantResults.ToArray().ToList().IndexOf(Permission.Denied) == -1)
            {
                ShowMessage("Permissions granted");
            }
            else
                ShowMessage("Permission request denied, unable to continue.");
        }

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

Then in the service (not activity) I check the permission, get the folder, get the file, and try to play the mp3 with the MediaPlayer class:

```
    MediaPlayer player;


    public string GetSongDirectory()
    {
        string result = "";


        List<Java.IO.File> files = GetExternalFilesDirs(null).ToList();

        files = files.OrderBy(x => x.AbsolutePath.IndexOf("emulated")).ToList();

        var f = files.DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault();

        if (f != null)
        {
            result = f.AbsolutePath + "/songs";

            if (Directory.Exists(result) == false)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(result);
        }

        return result;
    }


    [return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        string songFolder = GetSongDirectory();

        var p = ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this.ApplicationContext, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage);

        if (p == Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string fileName in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(songFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    player = new MediaPlayer();

                    JFile f = new JFile(fileName);

                    Java.IO.FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);

                    player.Reset();
                    //player.SetDataSource(fileName); this didn't work either
                    player.SetDataSource(fs.FD, 0L, f.Length());
                    player.Prepare();
                    player.Start();

                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                x.ToString();
            }
        }


        Toast.MakeText(this, "Greetings from serivce", ToastLength.Long).Show();

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
```

However, on the call to Prepare, it throws the exception:

```
{Java.IO.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod
```

The fileName contains "/storage/1606-3C08/Android/data/com.companyname.mypod/files/songs/IshDARR - Alpha.mp3"

How can I play this mp3 file from my service in xamarin when it belongs to the external SD card?

Edit: I am able to read the file's content using BinaryReader so its not a file access permissions issue.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I need to play the user's music, not my own sound files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer online, but lost the original author so is how to play an mp3 from an external sd card on xamarain:

```
    public class StreamMediaDataSource : MediaDataSource
    {
        System.IO.Stream data;

        public StreamMediaDataSource(System.IO.Stream Data)
        {
            data = Data;
        }

        public override long Size
        {
            get
            {
                return data.Length;
            }
        }

        public override int ReadAt(long position, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
        {
            data.Seek(position, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return data.Read(buffer, offset, size);
        }

        public override void Close()
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                data.Dispose();
                data = null;
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);

            if (data != null)
            {
                data.Dispose();
                data = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a snippet:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
player.SetDataSource(new StreamMediaDataSource(sr.BaseStream));
player.Prepare();
player.Start();
```

I believe the reason why it was failing was because of the method it was using to read the file.

If I try to to read the file using FileStream. It throws a access denied exception even though it has had access granted through it through the user prompt.

This was the java log in case anyone needs to search it through google:

```
06-10 11:37:26.048 E/MediaPlayerNative(31944): error (1, -2147483648)
06-10 11:37:26.175 D/Mono    (31944): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
06-10 11:37:26.175 D/Mono    (31944): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_object_method'.
06-10 11:37:26.175 D/Mono    (31944): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_object_method'.
06-10 11:37:26.176 D/Mono    (31944): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_object_method'.
```